# How to calculate the total amount depend on the date in r?

Tags: r, sum

I am new to R and I have problems with calculating the amount of bill for each month. I have the dataframe as below:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  time = factor(c("Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast","Breakfast"), levels=c("Breakfast")), date=c("2020-01-20","2020-01-21","2020-01-22","2020-02-10","2020-02-11","2020-02-12"),
  total_bill = c(12.7557,14.8,17.23,15.7,16.9,13.2)
)
```

My goal is to calculate the amount spending on the `Breakfast` for each month so here we have two months and I want to get the total sum of January and February separately.

Any help for this would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the 'date' to `Date` class, get the `month`, and use that as grouping column and `sum` the 'total_bill'

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    group_by(time, Month = format(as.Date(date), "%B")) %>% 
    summarise(total_bill = sum(total_bill, na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   time [1]
#  time      Month    total_bill
#  <fct>     <chr>         <dbl>
#1 Breakfast February       45.8
#2 Breakfast January        44.8
```

We can convert it to 'wide' format, if that is needed

```
library(tidyr)
out <- dat %>%
     group_by(time, Month = format(as.Date(date), "%B")) %>% 
     summarise(total_bill = sum(total_bill, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
     pivot_wider(names_from = Month, values_from = total_bill)

out
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   time [1] 
#   time      February January
#  <fct>        <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 Breakfast     45.8    44.8
```

If we also need to group by 'year'

```
out <- dat %>%
     mutate(date = as.Date(date)) %>%
     group_by(time, Year = format(date, "%Y"), Month = format(date, "%B")) %>% 
     summarise(total_bill = sum(total_bill, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: How can I invoke each sum of these two months?

Comment: @Ben10 it is doing the sum separately on each month.  I updated with the output I got

Comment: Thank you again. I wanna ask you sth else? How can we move to chat?

Comment: @Ben10 you could use the same chat room last time.  can you please sent an invite

Comment: How to invite? I am new to this.

Comment: I dont know how to invite

Comment: @Ben10 I guess you can use the same room from that other post

Comment: You might want to add year in group_by clause so that the solution works when data include other years.  So instead of, group_by(time, Month = format(as.Date(date), "%B")) %>%  use group_by(time, Month = format(as.Date(date), "%Y-%B")) %>%

Comment: I found that room now but how to invite you in?

Comment: @Ben10 can you show the link to that room sso that i can get in

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213534/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-perform-the-operation-on-the-columns-of-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question?

```
sums <- tapply(dat$total_bill, format(as.Date(dat$date), "%B"), sum)
February  January 
 45.8000  44.7857
```

`sums`is a list: so if you want to access, for example, the datum for February, you can do this:

```
sums[1]
February 
    45.8
```

Alternatively, you can convert `sums` into a dataframe and access the monthly sums via the month names:

```
sums <-  as.data.frame.list(tapply(dat$total_bill, format(as.Date(dat$date), "%B"), sum))
sums$February 
    45.8
```

**Addition**:

Another (fun) solution is via regex: you define the dates as a pattern and, using `sub` plus backreference `\\1` to recall the two numbers between the dashes, reduce them to the months part:

```
tapply(dat$total_bill, sub("\\d{4}-(\\d{2})-\\d{2}", "\\1", dat$date), sum)
     01      02 
44.7857 45.8000
```

Comment: but How can I access for example ```dat$January``` or ```dat$February```?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
d_sum <- dat %>% 
  group_by(substr(date, 0, 7)) %>%
  summarise(sum = sum(total_bill))

d_sum
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  `substr(date, 0, 7)`   sum
  <chr>                <dbl>
1 2020-01               44.8
2 2020-02               45.8
```

Comment: How can I access each sum of each month?

Comment: not sure I understand, you can put the output into a new data.frame, for instance d_sum (see update)

Comment: @Ben10 d_sum["2020-01"] will give you for jan 20 and d_sum["2020-02"] will give you for Feb20 .